# WOT Bishop or Archer?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I am using valentine and am nearing 19.5 K goal of getting one of these two archer or bishop
please suggest which one should I buy/unlock.

P.S: I like hitting with high alpha damage regardless of reload time...
but I don't like sniper mode of a SPG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not like the sniper mode of SPG then really your only choice is to go with the Archer. The Bishop puts you on the road to the rest of the UK SPG line and in the higher tiers you will use the sniper mode almost exclusively in a SPG.

If hitting with high power regardless of reload time I recommend checking out the FV215b (183). You will need to grind trough another line of the UK tech line to get it, but the nickname of that tank is "the deathstar" because of it's high reload, high alpha damage shots.

Comment: what about the penetration??

Answer (score 0):

the bishop has a really short range for arty and its not the fastest of all, so basically u have to put yourself in harms way (aka nearer to the front lines where the fight is happening). Bishop will be a tricky one mostly due to its low alpha and short range, but it's reload is fast enough, so that compensates a bit. Things will get better when u reach tier 6, Fv304 or Bert the Avenger (basically a more mobile bishop)

As for your concern, hitting with high power (i assume u mean damage per shot) wouldn't be the forte of British artillery pieces, at least not until the higher tiers. You might wanna scout out SPGs of other nations like Americans and Germans.

For TD line, as mentioned by Xenos, the FV215b(183) would suit your description but that line goes from the Alecto at tier 4 and AT2 at tier 5, as opposed to your Archer.

Though the Archer still leads up to the tier 10 TD with insane alpha, the FV4005 Stage 2. Huge gun but paper armor with semi traversable turret. It is comparable with the deathstar (at least the gun, in terms of alpha) but you won't be bouncing much shots in it now. The Archer line is interesting too, with the Challenger, Charioteer (awesome), Conway and finally the FV4005. Its tier 6 would be Achilles, something like the American Tier 5 TD, "Wolverine", but with a better gun i suppose.

All in all, if you prefer high alpha while still being able to bounce shots, go through the alecto, at2 line, or if you like mobility throughout the line before ending up with the HUGEE gun, then go for the Archer line ;)

PS: archer goes backwards faster than it goes forwards, just like the Crusader SP

Good luck on the battlefield